# Get value from javascript into velocity

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, velocity

I have a javascript function which returns me a value . I need to get this value in a variable of my velocity template can someone please help me .
Below is the code I am trying . I know it is not correct I am not getting the value

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getCurrentUserTime(key)
{
var user;
     $.ajax({
        url: "/rest/1.0/compute/TST-30",
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            user = data.sla;
        } 
     });
     return user[0].remainingTime;
}
</script>

$key="test"
#set($time=getCurrentUserTime('$key'))
$time
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the function is trying to return user[0].remainingTime before ajax call has completed. I recommend you handle the return value with callback:

```
function getCurrentUserTime(key, callback) {
    var user;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/rest/1.0/compute/TST-30",
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            user = data.sla;
            if(callback && typeof callback === 'function') {
                callback(user[0].remainingTime);
            }
        } 
    });

}

getCurrentUserTime('$key', function(val) {
    // handle val
});
```

You can find lots of guides about using callback in javascript via google.

Comment: When i run only the javascript it works , I need the value in my velocity template . I cant do that even with a simple javascript function which return a string .